# Variable not defined error after defining variable in another function

Tags: python, variables, declaration

My IDE is telling me that the variable `multiplied` isn't defined:

```
def multiply():
    surrounding_x()
    
    multiplied = False
    x_index = chars.index("x")
    before_x = chars[x_index - 1]
    after_x = chars[x_index + 1]
    num = 2
    while num <= 50:
        if int(before_x) == num:
            print("X is being multiplied by " + str(num) + ".")
            multiplied = True
            return multiplied

            break
        else:
            num += 1 

    if num  == 50:
        print('X is not being multiplied. ')
```

Here is where I defined the variable `multiplied` as `True`.

```
def order():
    division()
    addition()
    subtraction()
    multiply()

    if multiplied == True:
        pass
    if division == True:
        pass
    if addition == True:
        pass
    if subtraction == True:
        pass
```

All of the other variables (`division`, `addition`, and `subtraction`) have similar if not identical syntax defining them.

I tried renaming the variable. I thought that maybe I had made a spelling mistake. I have no idea what could be causing this, so if someone could help that would be awesome. As a beginner programmer, I think the answer to the problem is probably very simple but I don't yet understand it.

Comment: I recommend that you read about variable scope. You defined a variable named `multiplied` in the `multiply()` function. The `order()` function is unable to see that variable because of the python scoping rules. If you need to share variables between functions, you will need to add parameters or return values to your functions. These are two more concepts that you should learn about.

Comment: "All of the other variables (division, addition, and subtraction) have similar if not identical syntax defining them." - they are not defined anywhere at all in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables exist within a scope, and those variables do not pass between scopes unless you specify them to. Here, in the scope within the function `order`, there are four functions that exist within this scope, `addition`, `multiply`, `subtraction`, `division`. Note, these are **functions** not variables.

As such, you use the *variable* `multiplied` within the scope of the function and the scope within `order` cannot see this variable. Now, division, subtraction, and addition seem to work because you are using the same name as the *function*, it is not the variable that you are likely trying to access.

You do return your variables within the functions, but you are not storing them as anything in the scope of `order`. Additionally, if the outputs are boolean, you don't need to write `if val == True` because that can be the same as `if val` because `val` is either `True` or `False`.

Try this instead:

```py
def order():
    div = division()
    add = addition()
    sub = subtraction()
    mult = multiply()

    if mult:
        pass
    if div:
        pass
    if add:
        pass
    if sub:
        pass
```

Comment: You're more than welcome, good luck! As another commenter suggested always worth reading more about this if you want to, [for example](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/python_scope.asp).